# Faster R code if less number of lines

Tags: r, performance

I have a question about R code. Is it true that if you write a statement over several lines of code, when it is also possible to do it in one line, the code is faster? So, lesser lines means faster execution?

Example:

```
fileName = paste(directory, "fileTest.csv", sep="")
vars = read.csv(fileName, header=F)
vars = as.matrix(vars)
```

or

```
vars = as.matrix(read.csv(paste(directory, "fileTest.csv", sep=""), header=F))
```

I can imagine that only once it does not matter, but if this happens a lot in your code?

Comment: not sure about the speed but in the first code your assigning two variables which is worse than just creating one (second variable). I think it's always a trade between performance and readability.

Comment: Another option you may wish to consider is piping with `%>%` which can add readability to you code without intermediates.

Comment: you could test it with `microbenchmark::microbenchmark`. Doubt it makes any real difference - readability is more important

Comment: In your example I would expect most of the time to go to the read operation. The other two instructions would have a much lesser weight.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let's compare three functions: a function with 3 lines, a function with one line and a function that uses pipes.

```
library(microbenchmark)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

directory <- getwd()
mat <- matrix(rnorm(n=20000),nrow=200)
write.table(mat,"matrix.txt",sep="\t")

# 3-line code
fn1 <- function()
{
  fileName = paste0(directory,"/matrix.txt")
  vars = read.delim(fileName,header=T)
  as.matrix(vars)
}

# 1-line code
fn2 <- function()
{
  as.matrix(read.delim(paste0(directory,"/matrix.txt"),header=T))
}

# using pipe
fn3 <- function()
{
  paste0(directory,"/matrix.txt") %>%
          read.delim(.,header=T) %>%
          as.matrix()
}
```

Now, run each function 1000 times and measure run times. Plot the results.

```
mb <- microbenchmark::microbenchmark(fn1(),fn2(),fn3(),times=1000)
ggplot2::autoplot(mb)
```

[image]

I don't think the difference in speed is significant. But there are other factors (as mentioned in the comments) like how much memory is used by creating intermediary variables, code readability etc.

In my opinion it is better to use extra lines for better readability. This makes it easier to edit/modify code later on. Sometimes, having intermediate variables can be helpful to debug. If you have a lot of things going on, it is probably a good idea to remove variables that are no longer needed.

Comment: Thank you for your useful answer. Yes, readability is worse when putting everything on one line, so I'll just stick with using multiple lines, but try to keep the intermediate variables low.